# OpenMP parallel code slower

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have two loops which I am parallelizing

```
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nj; j++) {
      C[i][j] = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < nk; ++k)
        C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
    }
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nl; j++) {
      E[i][j] = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < nj; ++k)
        E[i][j] += C[i][k] * D[k][j];
    }
```

Strangely the sequential execution is much faster than parallel version above even using large number of threads. Am I doing something wrong? Note that all arrays are global. Does this make that difference?

Comment: Since C99, C has `for`-loop local variables. Just help the compiler and use them.

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iterations of your parallel outer loops share the index variables (`j` and `k`) of their inner loops. This for sure makes your code somewhat slower than you probably expected it to be, i.e., your loops are not ["embarrassingly"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) (or "delightfully") parallel and parallel loop iterations need to somehow accesses these variables from shared memory.

What is worse, is that, because of this, your code contains [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). As a result, it will behave nondeterministically. In other words: your implementation of parallel matrix multiplication is now incorrect! (Go ahead and check the results of your computations. ;))

What you want to do is make sure that all iterations of your outer loops have their own private copies of the index variables `j` and `k`. You can achieve this either by declaring these variables within the scope of the parallel loops:

```
int i;

#pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
    int j1, k1;  /* explicit local copies */
    for (j1 = 0; j1 < nj; j1++) {
      C[i][j1] = 0;
      for (k1 = 0; k1 < nk; ++k1)
        C[i][j1] += A[i][k1] * B[k1][j1];
    }
  }        
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
    int j2, k2;  /* explicit local copies */
    for (j2 = 0; j2 < nl; j2++) {
      E[i][j2] = 0;
      for (k2 = 0; k2 < nj; ++k2)
        E[i][j2] += C[i][k2] * D[k2][j2];
    }
  }
```

or otherwise declaring them as `private` in your loop pragmas:

```
int i, j, k;

#pragma omp parallel for private(j, k)
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nj; j++) {
      C[i][j] = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < nk; ++k)
        C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
    }
#pragma omp parallel for private(j, k)
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < nl; j++) {
      E[i][j] = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < nj; ++k)
        E[i][j] += C[i][k] * D[k][j];
    }
```

Will these changes make your parallel implementation faster than your sequential implementation? Hard to say. It depends on your problem size. Parallelisation (in particular parallelisation through OpenMP) comes with some overhead. Only if you spawn enough parallel work, the gain of distributing work over parallel threads will outweigh the incurred overhead costs.

To find out how much work is enough for your code and your software/hardware platform, I advise to experiment by running your code with different matrix sizes. Then, if you also expect "too" small matrix sizes as inputs for your computation you may want to make parallel processing conditional (for example, by decorating your loop pragmas with an `if`-clauses):

```
#pragma omp parallel for private (j, k) if(ni * nj * nk > THRESHOLD)
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
     ...
  }
#pragma omp parallel for private (j, k) if(ni * nl * nj > THRESHOLD)
  for (i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Or just use `for`-local variables. C has it, OpenMp has it. With some good habits, things work much more smoothly :)

Comment: @JensGustedt I would use it, but I don't know what input I can get! I am working on automatic parallelization, I identify the loops which don't have dependency and insert openmp pragmas for it.

Comment: @JensGustedt C only has them since C99. In particular, C89 does not have them.

Comment: @TejasPatel, I don't see the relationship. By `for`-loop variable I mean something like `for (int i = 0; i < ni; ++i)`. If you'd use that construct from the start in your code, your problem would never have arisen.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans, a good reason to move to a decent compiler. C99 is out since 15 years now.

Comment: @JensGustedt I do get your point. But I have to assume the worst case for my compiler. I don't have control over programs that user give to my compiler. I am writing a parallel compiler and above is part of a benchmark code which I am using for testing

Comment: @TejasPatel Then something went wrong with identifying such loop as these loops do carry so-called antidependencies (aka WAR- or write-after-read dependencies).

Comment: Any compiler that implements OpenMp should have a mode that accepts that construct. Don't program for the dinosaures.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Do you mean the loop variables? I am using LLVM IR and I can handle them separately so thats not a problem

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes I agree, but its a school project so I have to assume the worst to get grades

Comment: @TejasPatel The antidependencies are induced by the *inner* loop variables. Have you considered using Pareon as a reference (shameless plug!)?

Comment: @JensGustedt You don’t always have the choice. In particular, when writing a code processor of some sort.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Than I am taking care of induction variables so thats ok. I didn't know about Pareon until today. However it looks its not open source. I want to release my code as open source version after my semester. By any chance are you on its development team?

Comment: @TejasPatel Absolutely, I am. Hence, the “shameless plug”. I was by means trying to “trick” you into buying it. ;) Just wanted to point out that dependence analysis for C is far from trivial. Have you for example thought about the possibility that, in your example code, A, B, C, D, and E may be aliases for a single array? :) Seems like a hard nut to crack in the context of a school project. ;)

Comment: @TejasPatel But of course not only induction variables give rise to antidependencies.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Yes I have considered they might analysis. So I am  running an alias analysis pass before running dependency analysis. I did't know it would grow into something such large when I gave project proposal. More than 5K lines and counting. And yes induction var itself don't give rise to dependencies. So I have implemented various tests like SIV, MIV ,ZIV.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Any prospects of jobs at your company on basis of this project? :)

Comment: @TejasParel You’re always welcome to apply. But let’s not abuse Stack Overflow for chatting. This thread is already way too long.

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Why don't you put `i` on the list of private variables? My guess is that you expect that using the `for-directive` above the `for-loop` will handle the case of `i` as private and I agree with that. But when I use `i` as private on an example of my own I non expectantly get a faster implementation. So what's the case?